# How can git convert text to the machine's default character encoding?

Tags: r, github, emacs, character-encoding, rstudio

**The context**: I often collaborate on some repository, mostly with `R` scripts and `csv` files. I use `emacs` to edit text in a linux machine, colleagues seem to rely on `RStudio` in mac machines. Text files are written in `utf-8`, my `emacs` default character encoding. We exchange commits via gitHub.

**What happened**: When pulling commits created by colleagues, diacritical characters get messed up, probably due to `Rstudio` relying on a different default character encoding.

**What I wish**: I remember seeing a workaround this problem years ago, which I can no longer find. I'd like to set up the repository in such way that it will either force `utf-8` across the board, or determine the machine editor's default character encoding and convert text files accordingly. The idea is that whoever edits/commits/pulls/pushes will see diacritical characters correctly in their machine.

---

Thanks to @Smitop for help clarifying the problem.

Comment: Linux doesn't have any "default" character encoding for file contents, and I don't think MacOS has one either.

Comment: Thanks @Smitop, this helps clarify the question. Is it the text editor's default that I should mention in an edited version of the question?

Comment: Yes, it seems the problem is that you are writing in UTF-8 but your colleagues are using something else. It really depends on what text editors are being used. If the text editors involved support the `.editorconfig` standard, specifying [`charset`](https://editorconfig.org/#supported-properties) might work.

Comment: *File data* is largely sacrosanct in Git (with the big exception being the built in CRLF/LF conversion options). File *names* can be problematic since Git must manipulate them in cooperation with the OS, but file *data* are just raw byte streams, to Git. You can, however, add so-called "smudge" and "clean" filters to process file data as it moves in and out of Git. Remember that *working tree files* are not actually *in* Git, so there is a "copy into Git" phase and a "copy out from Git" phase: this is where CRLF manipulation happens. The filters go here as well, if/when you write them.

Comment: The real tricks here will be (1) determining what kind of encoding each user wants; (2) writing clean and smudge filters that handle this; and (3) getting everyone to actually install and use these filters. This assumes that the problem is tractable: it's possible that different users, even on the same OS, want different encodings, in which case it's probably not a good idea to try to automate it at the Git/worktree interconversion point.

Answer (score 2):

Git definitely prefers text files to be in UTF-8, but it doesn't require this.  You can use any relevant encoding that you like.  There are two ways to ensure that you can configure files to always be in UTF-8.

First, you can use [an `.editorconfig` file](https://editorconfig.org/) to set the character set of files to UTF-8.  The idea behind this type of file is that it provides an editor-agnostic way to declare things like indentation and character sets that works across editors.  However, not all editors support it out of the box, so a plugin is required for those that don't.  RStudio doesn't seem to natively support it.

It is also possible to set the working tree encoding for files by editing a `.gitattributes` file.  In your case, the proper default encoding is UTF-8, so users who want to use a different encoding (say, Windows users using UTF-16) could create a `.git/info/attributes` file that contains something like this:

```
*.r working-tree-encoding=UTF-16
```

You can do this in the `.gitattributes` file in the repository if you always want to use a specific encoding in the working tree (say, because you use a program which cannot handle UTF-8), but that's not the case here, where you want to allow users to choose their own encoding.

A third approach you could take is to set up a CI system and reject commits where the files are not in UTF-8 encoding.  Users are then forced to fix their systems to properly handle the encoding.

I will point out that in general, both Linux systems and Macs tend to prefer UTF-8, so it is surprising to me that you're having this problem.